# Share component functionality (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, data-binding, components, siblings

I have two main components, one is the `main-well`(which has a router-link for displaying different components) and the second is a component for a right side `pop-out` that needs to be available on every page of the app. I wish to control the hide and show action of this `pop-out` from within the routed component (a descendant of `main-well`).

Parent page:

```
<page-area style="display: inline-block">
  <main-well></main-well>
  <pop-out></pop-out>
</page-area>
```

MainWell.component.html:

```
<div class="fill-whole-page">
  <router-link></router-link>
</div>
```

PopOut.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="show" class="pop-out-action pop-out-style">
  <button>Add</button>
  <button>Remove</button>
  <button>Copy</button>
</div>
```

The component that opens inside the `<router-link>` needs to be able to tell `pop-out` when to show and hide.

How do you manipulate the controls (or access the the component functions) of the sibling component of a parent or grandparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, a Service seems to be the natural way to allow interaction between components. The mechanism is described in the  [Component Interaction section of the official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

The basic idea - the service is injected in the `pop-out` component and whatever service needs to interact with it. The `pop-out` registers itself with the service and the consumers call methods on the service to interact with the `pop-out`.

Comment: Thank you... I can see how this might work. I will see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you describe seems to fit the usage of "named outlets".

You could refactor your parent component to have a named router outlet:

```html
<page-area>
  <main-well></main-well>
  <router-outlet name="popout"></router-outlet>
</page-area>
```

Then, in your route definitions, add a *secondary route* binding the `PopOutComponent` to the `popout` outlet :

```ts
{
  path: 'pop-out',
  component: PopOutComponent,
  outlet: 'popout'
},
```

Finally, whenever you need to display the popout (from ANYWHERE in your app), use a link activating that secondary route:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popout: ['pop-out'] } }]">Show Popout</a>
```

Or activate the route programmatically:

```ts
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popout: ['pop-out'] } }]);
```

Check out the doc if this seems like a valid solution for your use case: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#named-outlets

*Additional consideration:* It should work well if the only type of communication you need between any component and the popout is show/hide. If you need to pass data to the popout, then you'd have to use a service.

Comment: Nice idea. Regarding data - you could still pass data to the popout via URL params. The only consideration is whether one wants to have the popout state be reflected in the URL. Depending on the situation, this may or may not be desirable. In case of dialogs, this is usually not desirable, but there may be situation where the opposite is true.

Answer (score 0):

If your component is not reachable in template, for example it is dynamic and created inside router-outlet, then you could use shared service and Pub/Sub pattern. There were couple of answer on stackoverflow, also see article [Pub Sub in Angular](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/pub-sub-in-angular-2.0)